# How do I give objects with the same texture, a different viewport color?

Tags: texturing, 3d-view, color

I made some kind of robot and I wanna make the armor red in viewport and the base parts of the robot blue. When I try to do this, all the objects with the same texture become that color and not only the ones I want. The robot has 300+ parts so I hope there's a rather fast way to solve this! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, select one of the desired objects and give it a new material with a new color.

[image]

[image]

Then pick all the other elements you want to change the material on.  You can add to the current selection with <kbd>Shift</kbd> + Click.  Finally select the object with the new material.

[image]

Then you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> and select Materials to carry the material of your last selection over to all the other selected objects.

[image]

[image]